# keyboard event as3 not working

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder, flash-cs5

This was something that had me banging my head for 2 hours before I figured it out.
I decided to post it here, to help others not pull their hair out :).

Essentially the bug was I was not receiving the keyboard event from within my flash builder environment (The same bug/issue is visible with adobe flash cs5). I set the stage.focus = stage, did not help. I added other event listeners (mouse_down, frame_enter) which worked fine, I added MovieClip children and listened for events on those children, still the same issue.

```
package
{
  public class Test extends Sprite 
  {

    public function Test() 
    {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
    }

    public function init(stage:Stage):void 
    {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyReleased);
    }


    private function keyPressed(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
    {
        trace("keyPressed");
    }

    private function keyReleased(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
    {
        trace("keyReleased");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this code working or is it not working?

Comment: This code was NOT working, exactly as stated above. The question was WHY was it not working. I finally figured it out, posting the question here for others to answer (or I will eventually answer it myself). A clue, the environment was the cause of the error.

Answer (score 4):

Using keyboard commands requires listening to keyboard events. This process is identical to the process for listening to any other event in AS3. You need to use the **addEventListener()** method to register with a **KeyboardEvent**. However, unlike other objects, due to the fact that the keyboard is not necessary attached to any specific object in the project, the **Keyboard Event** is usually registered with the **stage**. In the code below, the stage object registers for a keyboard event to be triggered each time a keyboard key is pressed down.

**Unlike in AS2, in AS3 Keyboard events are not global. They are issued to the stage, and they bubble through the display list to whatever display object has focus.**

```
package
{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

  public class Test extends Sprite 
  {
   public function Test() 
   {
     init();
   }

   public function init():void 
   {
      stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
      stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyReleased);
   }


   private function keyPressed(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
   {
      trace("keyPressed");
   }

   private function keyReleased(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
   {
    trace("keyReleased");
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public function init(stage:Stage):void 

ADDED_TO_STAGE is a `listener Event` not a stage instance.
```

so instead of `stage:Stage` use `event:Event`.

and u needs to import needed classes.

Answer (score 1):

Marked the line that changed. Your code doesnt compile btw, check for error logs.

```
package  {

import flash.display.Sprite; /// changed line
import flash.events.Event; /// changed line
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent; /// changed line


public class Test extends Sprite 
{

public function Test() 
{
    this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
    /* i like it this way
    stage ? init(null) : addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
    */

}

public function init(e:Event):void  /// changed line
{
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyReleased);
}


private function keyPressed(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
    trace("keyPressed");
}

private function keyReleased(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
    trace("keyReleased");
}
}

}
```